# Create a custom business day frequency for pandas.date_range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, datetimeoffset

Let's assume we want to build a `DatetimeIndex` object consisting of all Mondays and Thursdays in 2023. How would one go about doing this using pandas?

Specifically, I have the *start* and *end* of a time period and I want to create the following `Datetime` object:

```
pd.date_range(start, end, freq)
```

The problem I am having is I don't know how to captures the said days of the time period as I am not sure what to put for *freq*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use pandas business daterange with weekmask:

```
pd.bdate_range('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31', freq='C', weekmask='1001000')
```

Alternatively you can use boolean indexing to filter the required day names:

```
d = pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31')
d[d.day_name().isin(['Monday', 'Thursday'])]
```

Result

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-02', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-09', '2023-01-12',
               '2023-01-16', '2023-01-19', '2023-01-23', '2023-01-26',
               '2023-01-30', '2023-02-02',
               ...
               '2023-11-27', '2023-11-30', '2023-12-04', '2023-12-07',
               '2023-12-11', '2023-12-14', '2023-12-18', '2023-12-21',
               '2023-12-25', '2023-12-28'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=104, freq=None)
```